# How to prove the strong convexity of the trace distance?

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, density-matrix, information-theory, trace-distance

On page $408$ of Nielsen & Chuang in the step going from equation $(9.48)$ to $(9.49)$, I don't see how:

$$\sum\limits_i (p_i - q_i)tr(P \sigma_i) \leq D(p_i, q_i)$$

I proceed as follows:

$$\sum\limits_i (p_i - q_i)tr(P \sigma_i)\leq \sum\limits_i |p_i - q_i| tr(P \sigma_i)$$

How is this $\leq \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_i |p_i - q_i|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of indices $i$ such that $p_i\ge q_i$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_i(p_i-q_i)\mathrm{tr}(P\sigma_i)\le&\,\sum_{i\in A}(p_i-q_i)\mathrm{tr}(P\sigma_i)\tag1\\
\le&\,\sum_{i\in A}(p_i-q_i)\tag2\\
\le&\,\max_S\sum_{i\in S}(p_i-q_i)\tag3\\
=&\,D(p,q)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
where in the first step we drop non-positive terms, in the second we use $\mathrm{tr}(P\sigma_i)\le 1$, in the third we take maximum over subsets $S$ of the index set and in the final step we use $(9.4)$ on page $401$.

Comment: Thank you Adam. How do I prove tr$(P\sigma_i) \leq 1$? It seems intuitive as P is a projection operator and tr$(\sigma_i) = 1$.

Comment: Choose a basis $\psi_i$ with $i=1,\dots,k$ of the image of $P$ and extend it to a basis $\psi_i$ with $i=1,\dots,n$ of the full Hilbert space . Then $\mathrm{tr}(P\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle\psi_i|\sigma|\psi_i\rangle\le\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\psi_i|\sigma|\psi_i\rangle=\mathrm{tr}(\sigma)=1$.